# how to add a title (or legend) when plotting a decision tree in sklearn (with plot_tree)

Tags: python, plot, scikit-learn, visualization, random-forest

I have the following random forest classifier graph that I get with `plot_tree` of sklearn :

[image]

But I would like to add a legend (or title) somewhere with the hyperparameter values that I used to train my model. The problem is that such an argument is not present when using `plot_tree`, how would you handle it to add these informations to the above plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot_tree` plots on the current matplotlib.pyplot axes by default.  From there you can make use of matplotlib functionality.  If you want, you can use the `ax` parameter to plot onto a specified axes object instead; in the below example you don't really need to call the `figure` and `axes` lines, but it might be helpful depending on how you end up decorating the plot.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
tree.plot_tree(clf, ax=ax)
plt.suptitle("Decision Tree")
hp_text = '\n'.join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in clf.get_params().items())
plt.text(1.0, 0.25, hp_text, transform=plt.gca().transAxes);
```

[image: iris dataset decision tree, with parameters as subtitle]